# Bramble Pi as Minecraft Server

Tags: server, minecraft

Im looking to build a Minecraft Server running on a Raspberry Pi Cluster. Is there any available software that would support this?

Comment: Do you mean the normal Minecraft server, or the Pi-Edition? You'll probably need the new 512 MB Pi to even attempt to run the regular server.

Comment: I mean the regular edition of minecraft server or one that would be playable by computer users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minecraft.**

```
http://pi.minecraft.net/
Download: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.minecraft.net/pi/minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
Decompress: tar -zxvf minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
To run it: cd mcpi
Followed by: minecraft-pi
```

**Minecraft server** <sup>http://picraftbukkit.webs.com/pi-minecraft-server-how-to</sup>

Install JAVA HardFloat

```
sudo wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk8/archive/b102/binaries/jdk-8-ea-b102-linux-arm-vfp-hflt-07_aug_2013.tar.gz
mkdir -p /opt
sudo tar zxvf (name of package) -C /opt
rm (name of package)
sudo /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -version
```

Then download and extract the spigot version of the MineCraft server ans run the JAR. this is for 256 use 496 for 512 Pi. I takes time to generate the maps.

```
sudo wget http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/lastStableBuild/artifact/Spigot-Server/target/spigot.jar
sudo /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -Xms128M -Xmx256M -jar /home/pi/spigot.jar nogui
```

**Clustering of minecraft** <sup>http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/High-Availability_Cluster</sup>

Setting clustering up is a very long and involved process but essentially you need to install DRBD which is is a block device replication daemon. Pacemaker is the utility that will manage all the services and ensure they stay running.

Basically each data store is replicated on each Pi so the data us synchronised on all the Pi's. Each Pi runs its own version of the minecraft server so if any Pi goes down the server will keep running.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the things in your answer. Links are not answers to a question. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to copy and paste the whole article but you could summarize the pertinent info.